# How to make communicate .Net core API, swagger and sql database via docker-compose

Tags: .net, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to deploy a .Net core API with swagger openAPI in it. It works well on my computer with visual studio. I can access it at the address : localhost:5000/swagger/index.html but when i try to deploy it with docker, I can't access the webpage

The .net application seems to communicate well with the sql database, I have no errors on the docker logs of the two containers but when I go to the IPAddress indicated by the "docker inspect" command on the web_API_container, I have a 404 not found page. The IP address is accessible (also with ping) but I can't access the web page of swagger.

here is my docker-compose

```
version: "3"
services:
    web:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "5000:80"
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
        environment:
            SA_PASSWORD: "password"
            ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

and here, my Dockerfile for the .net app :

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 5000

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TestAPI/TestAPI.csproj", "TestAPI/"]
COPY ["Abstract/Abstract.csproj", "Abstract/"]
COPY ["ClassLibrary1/Entities.csproj", "ClassLibrary1/"]
COPY ["DataAccessLayer/DataAccessLayer.csproj", "DataAccessLayer/"]
COPY ["Services/Services.csproj", "Services/"]

RUN dotnet restore "TestAPI/TestAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/TestAPI"
RUN dotnet build "TestAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TestAPI.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestAPI.dll"]
```

I have also tried to map port 80 to 80 instead of 5000 to 80 in the docker-compose because I read that .Net core app are on port 80 in production but it didn't worked better...

thanks for your help !

Comment: I've just tried setting up your docker-compose config with a web-api example project (found here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio-code) and the app is available on port 5000. Maybe the problem isn't connected to your docker config? Is swagger available if you run the app outside docker?

Comment: thanks for your help, yes, the project works fine outside docker. But i can't understand why it isn't possible to access the web app in docker... I will try your web-api example.

Comment: That just might guide you to the issue. I had to trim the Dockerfile down a bit, this is how it looks now - https://gist.github.com/yaron-idan/59e0f88cf7d15fa1e20045386a0e808d

Comment: I used the exact same Dockerfile as you but impossible to access the todoApi neither. Which IP adress are you looking on the web browser ? I did a "docker inspect on the web container and got (for me) "IPAddress": "172.20.0.3". But neither port 80 nor port 5000 works... I got a 404 not found error.

Comment: Oh, I think I understood what's going on. You should access the app on `localhost`, or `127.0.0.1`. Docker is forwarding port 80 from your container to port 5000 on your local machine. The private ip of the container isn't accessible to you, it is used for internal network between containers, and that's what you've received from `docker inspect`

Comment: if my answers helped you solving the issue let me know and I'll post it as an answer so other people having the same issue will know the answer.